# Flow bool, boolean and Boolean

Tags: flowtype

The difference between the `boolean` and `Boolean` types in flow is [documented](https://flowtype.org/docs/builtins.html#boolean).

However, I failed to find a mention of the `bool` type that apparently is also accepted. The below typechecks fine with `0.35.0`:

```
let b1: bool    = true;
let b2: boolean = true;
b1 = !b2;
b2 = !b1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are equivalent, and both are supported for legacy reasons (I don't know the full context here). However, `boolean` is recommended for consistency.

Comment: yes, they are equivalent. Here's the relevant code in the parser https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/03d46fd859dab14819c242d7d5263e7005eab6f4/src/dts/parser_dts.ml#L530-L531